# Не получается изменить фон через :checked на css

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой код, по идеи при нажатии на radio кнопку должен backround цвет div`a, но этого почему-то не происходит. Вроде все просто, но не понятно. Буду благодарен за помощь!

```css
.test{
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 background: #000;
}
.check-game-blue:checked + .test{
 background: blue;
}
.check-game-red:checked + .test{
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="drop"><input type="radio" name="check-game" class="check-game-blue" checked>Синий</label>
<label class="drop"><input type="radio" name="check-game" class="check-game-red">Красный</label>
  
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: .check-game-red:checked ~ .test{
 background: red;
}

Comment: попробуйте знак тильда ~ вместо +

Comment: @Arendach , пробовал и так, но не работает.

Comment: Ни ~ ни + не сработают, поскольку input находится внутри label. Для того чтобы сработало нужно чтобы элементы были на одном уровне. Что собственно @Arendach и продемонстрировал в своем ответе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите `input` с тэга `label` и свяжите их по идентификатору

То есть тэгу `label` добавьте атрибут `for` чтобы получилось `<label for="input_id">...</label>`

Тэгу `input` добавьте атрибут `id` чтобы получилось `<input id="input_id" ...>`

```
<label for="blue" class="drop">Синий</label>
<input id="blue" type="radio" name="check-game" class="check-game-blue" checked>

<label for="red" class="drop">Красный</label>
<input id="red" type="radio" name="check-game" class="check-game-red">

<div class="test"></div>
```

В `css` следует использовать знак тильда `~` вместо плюса `+`.

Про разницу их можно [прочитать здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282375/difference-between-the-selectors-div-p-plus-and-div-p-tilde)